# プロキシ(proxy)サーバを経由するインターネット接続は一般的ですか？

Tags: pip, apt

いつもお世話になります。

私はとある学校で講師をしておりまして、PythonやLinux等をつかった授業を担当しています。

pipやaptなどでモジュールやパッケージ等をインストールしようとしたり、その他様々なツールからネットワーク経由でのダウンロードをしようとすると高い確率でproxy関連のエラー(証明書のエラーを含む)が発生し、うまくいかない状態です。

もちろん、私自身で調査を行い解決方法は把握しているのですが、この手順の授業での位置づけについて迷っています。

そこで質問なのですが、企業では「社外とhttp,https接続するには必ずproxyを経由する」といったネットワーク構成は一般的なのでしょうか？

私自身が過去に在籍したことのある企業では、いずれもproxy経由となっていました。

proxy経由の手順が一般的なのであればそのような位置づけで学生に教示する必要がありますし、一般的でなければ、こういう環境もまれにあるので気をつけるようにと教示する必要があります。

昨今では、pipやaptなどに限らず、開発環境自身が自分でアップデートする機能があるので、proxyをいちいち経由しないといけない、ということでは開発効率がかなり落ちるのではないかな、とおもってます。

私の想像では、各開発環境やyum,pip等では、公式サイト等ではproxyを経由した場合のやり方が書いておらず、stackoverflowなどにおいても関連する質問が古かったり数が少なかったりするので、proxy経由での接続は今やあまり一般的では無いのだと感じられます。

皆様いかがでしょうか。
教えていただけると助かります。

---

**追記: 2020/03/10 11:30**
※※※下記の質問については、[別の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/63721)を立てました※※※

```
皆様、コメントありがとうございます。何らかの手段でProxyを通すのは一般的なのですね。ダウンロード機能がある一部のソフトではProxyを使用すると証明書関連のエラーが発生します。証明書エラーを無視するという設定ができるソフトもあります。
最近はhttpsによる通信が一般的になっていることもあり、間にproxyが挟まって一旦proxyで復号化して中身を監視するような構成だと、原理的に証明書のエラーが発生します。

IEやChromeなどのブラウザであれば、ブラウザにProxyのルート証明書をインストールすれば証明書関連のエラーが解消できます。

そこで、次の質問なのですが、IoTや組み込み、その他のソフトウェア開発をおこなう企業では、Proxyの構成はどのようなものにするのが一般的なのでしょうか。

私はインフラ関連については疎いので、ネットで聞きかじったくらいしか知識がありませんが、
・https,httpについて、全部の通信を一旦復号化して監視・記録する
・httpだけを監視・記録する。httpsについては素通りにしてIPアドレスやドメイン名のみ記録する
....などがパターンとしては考えられるのかな...とおもいます。


個人的には、先行開発をメインにおこなう部署や会社では、Proxyとの格闘でかなり時間を費やしているんじゃないかな...とおもっています。
そのようば場合、素直にProxyと格闘するのか、情シスから緩和ルールをもらったりするのか...などどのように運用されているのか、なども教えていただけると嬉しいです。
```

Comment: ここでいうPROXYサーバ経由での接続というのは明示的に設定するPROXYサーバに限定される話でしょうか？それとも透過プロキシ(transparent proxy)を含む話でしょうか？

Comment: 主に「明示的に設定するPROXYサーバ」です。ただ、透過プロキシについてもツールによっては証明書エラーがでる場合があるような気がしているので、これについても教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: スタックオーバーフローについては一問一答形式になっておりますので、一般的かどうかについては、回答が済んでいると思いますのでこの課題は完了して。次にプロキシ構成とそれに対する対応については別途新しい質問を立てていただいたほうが良いでしょう。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございました。そのようにさせていただきます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

企業に限らず学校なども含め、LAN内に複数クライアントがある場合にプロキシ経由で外部に接続するのはセキュリティを確保するためにも一般的に利用されている方法だと思います。

プロキシの中でも特にwebフィルタリングを行うようなものについては、ブラウザでコンテンツを閲覧している分には問題ないのですが、質問に挙げられたようなパッケージ管理でファイルをダウンロードする際、証明書などのチェックを行う過程で問題が出るケースは私も経験があります。
(プロキシを通る際に証明書が置き換わって見えるため、パッケージ管理ツールが正当性をチェックする段階でエラーになってしまう)

設定方法も大抵は各マニュアルに記載があるかと思います。

- `man yum.conf`
- [`man apt.conf`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/apt.conf.5.ja.html)
- [Using a Proxy Server - pip User Guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server)

**参考:**
[ウィルス対策ソフトなどのURLフィルタリング機能とSSL証明書について](https://ssl.sakura.ad.jp/column/url-filtering/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり何らかの形でproxyを経由するのが一般的なのですね。大体のソフトではproxy経由の設定はできるものの、一部のソフトでは証明書のエラーへの対応ができなかったりするので困ることもあります...

Answer (score 0):

必須でしょうね。
ただし、それが可視化されているか、社員など企業内のエンドユーザーの普段の使い勝手にどれほど影響するか、等については経営者やシステム部門の裁量になるでしょう。

つい最近も、このサイトにこんな質問が来てプロキシについて言及されています。
[Anaconda以外でのPythonの環境構築について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/63606/26370)
[aws-google-auth で２段階認証前にエラーが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/63426/26370)

範囲が大きすぎるしれませんが、情報処理推進機構の情報セキュリティページとか、そこでの「PROXY」をキーワードにした検索結果です。
[HOME情報セキュリティ](https://www.ipa.go.jp/security/index.html)
[同サイトのproxyでの検索結果](https://www.ipa.go.jp/search.html?cx=010529523422831228604%3At0lwsqkoop8&cof=FORID%3A10&ie=UTF-8&q=proxy&imageField.x=0&imageField.y=0)

Comment: ありがとうございます。やはり必須の構成なのですね。リンクとても参考になりました。