# ソフトウェア開発をおこなう企業における一般的なProxy構成を教えて下さい

Tags: http, https

お世話になっております。

[皆様のご助力](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/63673/38053)もあり、企業や学校においてはProxyサーバを経由して社外ネットワークへアクセスするのが一般的であるということがわかりました。

最近はhttpsによる通信が一般的になっていることもあり、間にproxyが挟まって一旦proxyで復号化して中身を監視するような構成だと、原理的に証明書のエラーが発生します。

IEやChromeなどのブラウザであれば、ブラウザにProxyのルート証明書をインストールすれば証明書関連のエラーが解消できます。

pipやapt,yumなどを始めとするパッケージ管理ソフトや、モジュール等の自動ダウンロード機能がある一部のソフトではProxyを使用してhttpsでダウンロードしようとすると証明書関連のエラーが発生します。証明書エラーを無視するという設定ができるソフトもあります。

Proxyを経由する場合は、これらのソフトに対して様々な方法で対策をする必要があります。

そこで質問です、IoTや組み込み・業務系に限らず、ソフトウェア開発をおこなう企業では、Proxyの構成はどのようなものになっているのが一般的なのでしょうか。

私はインフラ関連については疎いので、ネットで聞きかじったくらいしか知識がありませんが、
・https,httpについて、全部の通信を一旦復号化して監視・記録する
・httpだけを監視・記録する。httpsについては素通りにしてIPアドレスやドメイン名のみ記録する
....などがパターンとしては考えられるのかな...とおもいます。

個人的には、先行開発をメインにおこなう部署や会社では、新しいツールを導入するときに、Proxyとの格闘でかなり時間を費やしているんじゃないかな...とおもっています。
（しかも、頻繁にバージョンアップなどあり、そのたびに設定方法が変わるとか...）

そのような場合、素直にProxyと格闘するのか、情シスから緩和ルールをもらったりするのか...などどのように運用されているのか、なども教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: これだとアンケートになっちゃいますので SO 向きではないかと。あと、具体的な構成がどうなっているとかは守秘義務とかあって答えられない人のほうが多いと思います。オイラも答えられません。

Comment: IT開発特化ではなく一般的なものなのでコメントで、この辺の記事でしょうか。[【図解】httpプロキシサーバの仕組み(http GET/https CONNECTメソッド)や必要性・役割・メリットデメリット・DNSの名前解決の順序](https://milestone-of-se.nesuke.com/nw-basic/grasp-nw/proxy/), [【ブラウザのプロキシ設定】ローカルアドレス,例外,自動構成スクリプト,WPAD,グループポリシー](https://milestone-of-se.nesuke.com/nw-basic/grasp-nw/proxy-configuration/), [大規模サイトの ネットワークセキュリティ](https://www.ipa.go.jp/security/fy14/contents/enterprise/pdf/enterprise.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ソフトウェア開発をおこなう企業

であれば

> pipやapt,yumなどを始めとするパッケージ管理ソフトや、モジュール等の自動ダウンロード機能がある一部のソフト

に対応するリポジトリサーバをイントラに持っていることも少なくないのではないでしょうか(一般的である、かどうかまではわかりませんが)。
例えば[JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.co.jp/artifactory/features/)や[Sonatype Nexus Repository](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository)はそのような目的を達成するためのプロダクトです。
(ミラー機能というのがあります)

エンドユーザ(ソフトウェア開発者)とリポジトリサーバ間の通信がイントラネットワークで完結すれば

> 証明書関連のエラーが発生

するような仕組みを差し挟む必要がそもそも無くなるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

おおむね、774RRさんのコメントに同意です。そのうえで
ピンポイントでコメント

> 個人的には、先行開発をメインにおこなう部署や会社では、新しいツールを導入するときに、Proxyとの格闘でかなり時間を費やしているんじゃないかな...とおもっています。

個人的には、先行開発が社内の通常ネットワークと同一LAN内で行われることに疑問があります。通常目的に応じてネットワークの役割を定義しそれぞれ別のルールで運用するなどやりそうですよね。それこそ一昔前の開発では開発LANとOALANは完全に独立させて、開発LANは一歩も外に出さないなんて普通にやってたことですよね。

で、この運用ルールとか、分割方針とか普通の会社が何年もかけて積み上げるノウハウなので、「ただでくれ」と言われても「はいこれで」とでないのが「普通」だと思います。（運用バレルと、そこを突かれたりとかいろいろあるし）

いずれにせよ、「一般的な」情報ではなく専門の業者に要件伝えて見積もり出させるのが、早くて簡単。そして結局お安いんじゃないですかね。。